# How do I make a simple <audio> element stay at the bottom of the browser window while scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, css, audio

I am using github to host html code for a website I am working on building and I would like to add an audio player to the bottom of the window wen scrolling. I did it at one point but the USB flash drive it was on corrupted and I lost the file forever. Anyone know an easy way to do this?
I did it without using a div and I would like to keep it that way.

Comment: position: fixed; bottom: 0

Comment: Can you share your code, what you have created?

Comment: The latest code is currently stored in the Github Repo. The file it Test.html at https://github.com/The-Unnamed-Engineer/Website-coding/tree/gh-pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about a little css tweak on the audio style attribute

bottom: 0; 
position: fixed; 
right: 0;

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's already set to that... However you may feel free to make changes to the git copy. I set it to auto for the right so it could try to center it.

Comment: I have checked it. You have used music class to define the css, but on the audio tag instead of giving audio tag class to music, you have given it style music. Please check it.
Also use right:0 in the css instead of auto if you want it at the bottom right of your page

Comment: I want it in the bottom middle of the page. class seems a little better.

Comment: No problem man. Class will work here, but you have to make sure that you write the name of the class in class attribute only. You ave had written it under style attributes. Check your GitHub post. I've forked the changes.

Comment: Changing it to class has fixed the problem I was having.

Comment: Awesome. Cheers mate

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS styling

HTML and CSS

```
<html>
<style>
    #fixed{
        position:fixed;
        bottom:0px;
        right:0px;
    }
</style>
<body>
<audio id = "fixed" controls>
<source src = "audio.mp3" type = "audio/mpeg">
</audio>
</body>
</html>
```

Check out the snippet...hope this is what you want!

```css
#fixed{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>End of Page
<audio id = "fixed" controls>
<source src = "audio.mp3" type = "audio/mpeg">
</audio>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would like to keep it all in the one .html file if possible.

Comment: I have updated the answer but i wont look like fixed until there is some data on the page. Like in snippet there were spaces of <br> tag. Comment if still any problems

Comment: Actually it's working now. I had style=music when it should have been class=music.

Answer (score 0):

```js
setTimeout(()=>{
        var player = document.createElement('audio');
        player.src = 'https://www.mboxdrive.com/Best%20Workout%20Music%20Mix%20%F0%9F%92%AA%20Gym%20Motivation%20Music%202021%20%F0%9F%92%AA.mp3';
        player.controls = true;
        player.style.position = "absolute";
        player.style.bottom = "0px";
        player.style.left = "0px";
        document.body.appendChild(player);
}, 0);
```

Comment: Remove duplicate code and add some explanation to your answer please

Comment: Ah yes....this is the simple mp3 player I use that is located on the bottom left! You can change the code based on preference!! However, you can get away without using the setTimeout feature!! :)